# Import image file from Kotlin to Python file to be processed by OpenCV

Tags: python, kotlin, opencv, chaquopy

I want to create a Kotlin-based program for Android to detect HSV values of an image imported from the gallery. Here is the image:
[01.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdcyc.jpg)
I already have the Python program to crop and threshold the image to obtain only the HSV from each circles. I only use the Kotlin to get the image from phone gallery and to parse obtained HSV data from Python. I'm not familiar with Kotlin and Chaquopy. I tried to integrate both files, but I'm having difficulties to transfer image array to the Python file. I don't know what kind of file type should be transferred to Python so it can be recognized by OpenCV.

Here is what I tried:

Kotlin:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityImportImageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnOpengallery.setOnClickListener {
            startGallery()
        }
    }

    private val launcherIntentGallery = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val selectedImg = result.data?.data as Uri
            selectedImg.let { uri ->
                binding.imageView.setImageURI(uri)
            }
            binding.btnNext.setOnClickListener {
                val bitmap = selectedImg.toString()
                val py = Python.getInstance()
                val module = py.getModule("pythonfile")
                val result = module.callAttr("main", bitmap)
                binding.textView.text = result.toString()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun startGallery() {
        val intent = Intent()
        intent.action = ACTION_GET_CONTENT
        intent.type = "image/*"
        val chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a Picture")
        launcherIntentGallery.launch(chooser)
    }
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import os
import math

# I already tried to create a function:
# def main (imgdir)
# return h,s,v,concresult

img = cv.imread(imgdir)
x,y=img.shape[1],img.shape[0]

#Cropping Area
midpointx=x/2
midpointy=y/2
widthx=x/4
widthy=x/4
x1,y1,w1,h1 = round(midpointx-widthx), round(midpointy-widthy), round(widthx), round(widthy)
x2,y2,w2,h2 = round(midpointx), round(midpointy-widthy), round(widthx), round(widthy)
x3,y3,w3,h3 = round(midpointx-widthx), round(midpointy), round(widthx), round(widthy)
x4,y4,w4,h4 = round(midpointx), round(midpointy),round(widthx), round(widthy)

#Crop Image
cropped1 = img[y1 : y1 + h1, x1 : x1 + w1]
cropped2 = img[y2 : y2 + h2, x2 : x2 + w2]
cropped3 = img[y3 : y3 + h3, x3 : x3 + w3]
cropped4 = img[y4 : y4 + h4, x4 : x4 + w4]
cv.imwrite("circle1.png", cropped1)
cv.imwrite("circle2.png", cropped2)
cv.imwrite("circle3.png", cropped3)
cv.imwrite("circle4.png", cropped4)

#Main
colorRGB = [[],[],[],[]]
colorHSV = [[],[],[],[]]
concresult = np.array([])

for i in range(4):
    img = cv.imread('circle'+str(i+1)+'.png')
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Masking Thresholding HSV
    lower = np.array([0, 0, 70])
    upper = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    result = cv.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
    gray = cv.cvtColor(result, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    _, alpha = cv.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Split RGB channels
    b, g, r = cv.split(result)

    # Merge RGBA
    rgba = [b, g, r, alpha]
    dst = cv.merge(rgba, 4)

    b = np.mean(b[alpha != 0])
    g = np.mean(g[alpha != 0])
    r = np.mean(r[alpha != 0])

    #HSV Convert
    r, g, b = r/255.0, g/255.0, b/255.0
    mx = max(r, g, b)
    mn = min(r, g, b)
    df = mx-mn

    if mx == mn:
        h = 0
    elif mx == r:
        h = (60 * ((g-b)/df) + 360) % 360
    elif mx == g:
        h = (60 * ((b-r)/df) + 120) % 360
    elif mx == b:
        h = (60 * ((r-g)/df) + 240) % 360

    if mx == 0:
        s = 0
    else:
        s = (df/mx)*100

    v = mx*100

    #Restore RGB
    r, g, b = r*255.0, g*255.0, b*255.0

    #Find Concentration
    y = s
    a = 6.14823
    b = 2.04579
    conc = (y-a)/b
    concresult = np.append (concresult, conc)

    #Delete Residual Files
    os.remove('circle'+str(i+1)+'.png')

#Debug Test Result
print(concresult)
```

Comment: OpenCV can deal with all common file formats, so choosing a file type is the least of your problems. More likely, you'll want to cut Python out and use OpenCV directly from Kotlin: https://opencv.org/android/

Answer (score 0):

`selectedImg` will be an Android `content` URI. To pass the image to Python, you'll first have to read the data from the URI, as shown in the [Chaquopy FAQ](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#faq-sdcard):

```
val content = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)!!.use { it.readBytes() }
myPythonModule.callAttr("process", content)
```

The Python function can then access the file content however you like:

```
def process(content):
    # `content` is already a bytes-like object, but if you need a standard bytes object:
    content = bytes(content)

    # If you need a file-like object:
    import io
    content_file = io.BytesIO(content)

    # If you need a filename (less efficient):
    import tempfile
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp_file:
        temp_file.write(content)
        filename = temp_file.name  # Valid only inside the `with` block.
```